# Origins of requesting prayer from people in Heaven?

Tags: prayer

I am wondering about the origin of the practice of people requesting prayers from people who have died and are assume to be in heaven (and also from angels)?  I know catholics and orthodox will claim that this has been going on since the apostles, and protestants claim that that it is essentially heresy and evil. I am looking for an objective response with some facts concerning the earliest recorded instances of Christians requesting prayers from people and angels in heaven.

Comment: Be sure to search for duplicates before asking next time.